# How to input array in .Autofilter command

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter a range in my active worksheet on the basis of one column's value through VBA.
The code is working when I pass single value but doesn't seem to work for an array/string.

My code is working for first two for example but not for the array:

```
Sub Filter()
Dim RefSheetF As Worksheet
Set RefSheetF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Arry(1 To 4) As String


If RefSheetF.Cells("B3") = "TOM" Then
    RefSheetF.Range("I9").AutoFilter _
 Field:=9, _
 Criteria1:=("127"), _
 VisibleDropDown:=True
 
 ElseIf RefSheetF.Cells("B3") = "DICK" Then
    RefSheetF.Range("I9").AutoFilter _
 Field:=9, _
 Criteria1:=("292"), _
 VisibleDropDown:=True

End If

If RefSheetF.Cells("B3") = "HARRY/ HARRIETTE / HERNANDES / HERMAN" Then
 RefSheetF.ShowAllData
 RefSheetF.AutoFilterMode = False
 Arry(1) = "394"
 Arry(2) = "426"
 Arry(3) = "5305"
 Arry(4) = "398"
    RefSheetF.Range("I9").AutoFilter _
 Field:=9, _
 Criteria1:=Arry, _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
 VisibleDropDown:=True
 End If
 
 If RefSheetF.Cells("B3") = "No Filter" Then
    RefSheetF.Range("I9").AutoFilter _
 Field:=7, _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
 VisibleDropDown:=True
 End If

End Sub
```

It doesnt show any error but just doesnt work for the array field! I have also tried using
Criteria1:=Array("394","426","398....

Comment: 'Reset the filter state' first with `If RefSheetF.FilterMode Then RefSheetF.ShowAllData: If RefSheetF.AufoFilterMode Then RefSheetF.AufoFilterMode = False`. Then try `Dim Arry(): ReDim Arry(1 To 4)`. The `VisibleDropDown's` parameter is `True` by default so it is redundant to use this argument in your case.

Comment: Added this  : 
RefSheetF.ShowAllData
RefSheetF.AutoFilterMode = False

after If statement(Array one)
Still doesnot seem to work, remains unchanged

Comment: `.Cells(3, 2)` is the same as `.Range("B3")` the latter being more readable. If it doesn't contain the exact match to `"HARRY/ HARRIETTE / HERNANDES / HERMAN"` (case-sensitive; are you sure there is no space between `HARRY` and the slash?) nothing will happen. After you have checked this, also change the invalid range address `"$A9:$AP"`.

Comment: Thanks, edited! And yes, it's the same value, I am copy pasting, checked for sensitivity by case also! It doesn't give any error, it doesn't change for array/string input!
It's working for single input, i.e., for Tom and Dick!

Comment: You didn't change the declaration of the array as suggested in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when in AutoFilter  use ONE CELL

```
RefSheetF.Range("I9").AutoFilter _
```

THEN THE FIELD IS 1

```
Field:=1, _
```

Looking at the code again, I saw that it has several other shortcomings, causing it not to run. I looked at it line by line and I think this is what you need:

```
'copy this SUB in the sheet module
'you can use the Me instead of RefSheetF
Sub Filter()
   'Dim RefSheetF As Worksheet
   Dim criteria As Variant, Arry(1 To 4) As String
   
   'Set RefSheetF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   'Select Case RefSheetF.Range("B3").Value2

   Select Case Me.Range("B3").Value2
   Case "TOM"
      criteria = "127"
   Case "DICK"
      criteria = "292"
   Case "HARRY/ HARRIETTE / HERNANDES / HERMAN"
      criteria = Array("394", "426", "5305", "398")
   Case "No Filter"
      Call No_Filters(Me)
      Exit Sub
   Case Else
      Exit Sub
   End Select
   Call No_Filters(Me)
   'RefSheetF.Range("A9:I9").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=True
   Me.Range("A9:I9").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=True
End Sub

'SHOW ALL DATA  
Public Sub No_Filters(ByRef r As Worksheet)
   With r
      If .FilterMode Then
         .ShowAllData
      End If
   End With
End Sub

'WHEN B3 CHANGING FIRE THE FILTER
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
      If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
         Call Filter
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very clean and understandable, worked like a charm!